# Only update time on datetimepicker, not date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Ok so I want to constantly update the time on my datetimepicker and I'm doing so as follows:

> ```
>     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         dtpTime.Value = DateTime.Now;
>     }
> ```
>
> The interval for timer1 is set to 1000 (milliseconds). The problem I am having is I also display the date on my datetimepicker and I do not want to change the date with the update, but by assigning DateTime.Now to dtpTime.Value, it updates the entire datetimepicker. I simply cannot find a way to only update the time.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: a `DateTimePicker` is typically used to allow a user to *select* a date/time. Constantly changing its value would make it very difficult for a user to do that. Does it definitely need to be a `DateTimePicker`, or could you use a `TextBox` and just format the text?

Comment: Without having to explain everything I'm trying to do, for the application of the program the user should not be able to change the time, only the date. A datetimepicker is the simplest way to accomplish what I want to do

Comment: An alternative would be to split the input into two. One for the user to select the date, the other a read-only field showing only the time component. Create your final `DateTime` by combining the two values.

Comment: yeah I'd rather not have to change all that poo throughout my entire program. There are several alternatives but adding one line of code seems to be the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to compose the value from the date of picker and the time of now?

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

dtpTime.Value = new DateTime(dtpTime.Value.Year, dtpTime.Value.Month, dtpTime.Value.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update to the current time, try using

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the **CustomFormat** property of the date picker to `hh:mm:ss` for time or `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` for date and time

and select `Custom` under the **Format** Property of **datetimepicker**

```
dtpTime.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

It will display the value according to custom format, list of formats are available here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this helps..